# Go folder structure same package

Tags: go

Let's say I want to order my project files like this:

```
- src
    - myProject
        - main.go
        - models
            - foo.go
            - bar.go
```

How can I tell the compiler about this structure, at the moment it looks that all my files have to be in the `myProject` folder, although with quite a few models, this will get crowded really quickly.

Is there a way I can achieve this structure without having to use external packages? (i.e. I still want to use the main package inside `models/foo`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) tool assumes one directory per package.

You can run the compiler and linker directly to achieve any layout you want. Because nobody does this, you will find that documentation to support this approach is slim.

Go with the flow. Use more than one package.

Comment: In addition, if you REALLY want it to feel the same, I believe you could put the models in "models" package and have main.go do: import . "./models" (so you dont have to refer to foo as models.foo)